# WebScraping findAll() does not get all the contents

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: the image shows the area that i want to access]

the image shows the area that i want to access

```
containers = pagebs('div',{'class':"search-content"})
```

when i print containers it just displays

```
[<div class="search-content">
</div>]
```

nothing inside it. I tried searching for tags inside in it that didn't work
is there a workaround or i just can't access it not matter what i do

this is what i've written so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
url = 'https://bahrain.sharafdg.com/?q=asus%20laptops&post_type=product'
uclient = uReq(url)
pagehtml = uclient.read() 
uclient.close()
pagebs = BS(pagehtml , 'html.parser')
containers = pagebs('div',{'class':"search-content"})
```

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: https://bahrain.sharafdg.com/?q=asus%20laptops&post_type=product

Comment: of course! The `search-content` div is empty.

Comment: What do you want to scrap from the website?

Comment: please add detailed code snippet

Comment: Rather than trying to extract the information from the HTML, you might find it faster (and easier) to extract it from the data that is returned from the server. As such it helps to know which information you are trying to extract rather than where it is in the HTML.

Comment: do you mean that i should use selenium webdriver

Comment: @Vin The contents that i searched for

Comment: It seems that the contents is not in page source and it is loaded dynamically. In this way, *Selenium* is the better choice for scraping.